# vba macros advancedfiltered method is not working properly

Tags: vba, filter, copy

I am working in VBA macros .using  advancedfilter method i trying to copy the unique records to other cells . it is working fine in one module with less code and less rows .

But the same advancedfiltered method is not working in another sheet . no data is copied and it is just showing extract in the left corner of the excel sheet .

basically I am using advancedfiltered method to copy the unique records from one column to another

could you please help to in rectifying the error in advanced filter option .

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

Set rng1 = ws.Range("B1")



rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=rng1, unique:=True



End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of `lastrow` for the problem sheet?

Comment: @tim williams nearly 40,000

Comment: @TimWilliams Is there any ways to remove duplicates and keep the unique values in the clolumn

Comment: Have you tried Data > Remove duplicates?

Comment: @TimWilliams : Ya it tried . It provides me solution

Answer (score 0):

Your `subroutine` seems to work fine. Can you please record a macro and see see what is the difference between your `sub's LastRow` and what's the exact `column A data Range rowcount`

```
Option Explicit

Sub advFilterCopy()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

   Set ws = Sheets(2)
   ws.Unprotect
   '--use this if you have a password
   '--ws.Unprotect Password:="urpassword"
   LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
   Set rng1 = ws.Range("B1")

   rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rng1, Unique:=True
   ws.Protect    '--user password if reqiured
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi i checked . Could you please check for the values for nearly 40k rows . and run the code for few times . Advancefilter is not working for many rows